# threads only work in multiples of 16

Tags: cuda

The following is my code for matrix addition. d_m and d_n are 2 matrices and d_s is the sum of those two.

The following is my kernel function :

```
__global__ void Matrix_Add(float *d_m, float *d_n, float *d_s, long long int a, long long int b)
{
    long long int i = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    long long int j = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if((i<a) && (j<b))
    {
        *(d_s + i*b + j) = *(d_m + i*b +j) + *(d_n + i*b + j);
    }

}
```

The following is my kernel launch :

```
dim3 DimGrid(ceil(a/16),ceil(b/16),1);
dim3 DimBlock(16,16,1);
Matrix_Add<<<DimGrid,DimBlock>>>(d_m,d_n,d_s,a,b);
```

I'm getting the sum only till the nearest multiple of 16 and rest all the sum is 0.

> Eg if 2 5*5 matrices are given as input the sum will be a 5*5 matrix
>   with all elements 0.

It only works if the matrix is 16*16, 32*16, 16 * 32. 32 * 32 etc (multiples of 32)

So how can i take care of the last sets of blocks launched so as to meet the boundary conditions ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your grid size calculations are badly broken, so you are not running enough blocks (or the launch is failing all together in the case where a or b are less than 16).

This:

```
dim3 DimGrid(ceil(a/16),ceil(b/16),1);
```

is performing a `ceil` operation on the result of *integer* division. Truncation has already occurred during the division, so no rounding by the `ceil` call can occur. For example

```
a = 20, b = 17
ceil(a/16) = ceil(20/16) = ceil(1) = 1
ceil(b/16) = ceil(27/16) = ceil(1) = 1
```

so only 1 block is run, and some of the input data is never processed (or if a or b are less than 16, you will try and launch 0 blocks, which is a runtime error).

Change the block calculation to something like this:

```
dim3 DimGrid((a + 15) / 16, (b + 15) / 16 ,1);
```

You could have diagnosed this for yourself simply by printing out the values of `DimGrid` at runtime.